# mysqli_fetch_array() error

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','db') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

    if(isset($_POST['rollNo'])){
        $rollNo = $_POST['rollNo'];

        $query = "Select * from table where ROLL_NUMBER LIKE '$rollNo'";
        $select = mysqli_query($con, $query);

        printf(mysqli_query($con));
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {
            echo $row['FIRST_NAME'];
        }


    }
?>
```

It is showing the error that

> mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given.

Comment: That's because your query failed. Also unrelated but you also have an SQL injection vulnerability in your code.

Comment: may query failing and return false  while your trying to pull data so its saying mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given.

Comment: I know about the injection part and not worried about it but why is the query failing. @Augwa

Comment: is there any table name like *table* ?

Comment: @JYoThI Yes there is a table.

Comment: var_dump($con); and know the connection string created or not

Comment: Use `echo mysqli_error($con);` to get the actual error message.

Comment: Thanks guys. It is resolved. SQL was not identifying the table.

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given.

This error raises in mysqli when you put the unknown column or table in the query for identifing the problem you can simply copy your query and paste it in phpmyadmin sql column and run it. it will respond you with the exect error code.

Answer (score -1):

Use below code segment

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo $row['FIRST_NAME'];
    }
```